# Как обернуть несколько болков в div без JQuery?

Tags: javascript

Как обернуть несколько блоков в новый `div` без использования JQuery?
В JQuery для подобных ситуаций используется wrapInner.

Comment: вы вроде не новичок здесь - хотя бы какой то код покажите

Comment: а точно wrapInner, а не просто wrap? Какая входная строка и ожидаемый результат?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```js
document.querySelector('input').onclick = () => {
  let newWrapper = document.createElement('div');
  newWrapper.classList.add('newWrapper');
  document.querySelectorAll('.item').forEach((item) => newWrapper.appendChild(item))
  document.querySelector('.wrapper').appendChild(newWrapper)
}
```

```css
.wrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: lightblue;
  width: 100px;
}

.newWrapper {
  padding: 10px;
  background: purple;
}

.item {
  background: pink;
  border: 1px dotted black;
}
```

```html
<input type="button" value="обернуть" />
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
  <div class="item">item</div>
</div>
```

Comment: у wrapInner другой результат